# $[n,n+1]=\text{ ??????}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know the answer is $n(n+1)$, but I'm having trouble formulating an argument.  I know by the definition, if I let $h=[n,n+1]$
$$h=nk_1, h=(n+1)k_2$$
$$nk_1=(n+1)k_2$$
$$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{k_2}{k_1}$$
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)k_2}{k_1}$$
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{h}{k_1}$$
$$n(n+1)=\frac{h(n+1)}{k_1}$$
So it appears the direct method is not working (unless I'm just not seeing it...)

I know if I start listing the multiples of each
$$\{n, 2n, 3n, \ldots, (n-1)n, nn,(n+1)n\}$$
$$\{(n+1), 2(n+1), 3(n+1),\ldots, n(n+1), (n+1)(n+1)$$
My goal then would be to show there are no terms equal smaller than $n(n+1)$.  So suppose suppose there is a smaller lcm.  Then 
$$an=b(n+1), b<a$$
with $a<(n+1), b<n$.  Then $an=bn+b<bn+a$

Thus, $an<bn+a \Rightarrow an-a<bn \Rightarrow a(n-1)<bn \Rightarrow \frac{a}{b}<\frac{n}{n-1}$  I am again stuck.

Comment: do you know the euclidean algorithm for finding greatest common divisor? you could do that to show that $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way, as mm-aops suggests, is to use the general relationship
$$
[m,n] = \frac{mn}{(m,n)}.
$$
In this case, that reduces the problem to showing that $(n,n+1)=1$, which is easier.

But if you want to do it straight from the definition: the general multiple of $n+1$ is $k(n+1)$. What's the smallest $k$ for which is this a multiple of $n$? When $1\le k\le n-1$, should be able to convince yourself that the remainder when $k(n+1)$ is divided by $n$ is $k$. In particular, none of those are multiples of $n$.